# LARAVEL - Show products to related category

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to show products related to the category. In my menu I have a list of categories if I click this category i want to see related products to this category. I'm just learning laravel can somebody help me out..

DATABASE:

```
 -categories: ID, NAME
 -products: has Category_id
```

View

```
Route::get('/category' , [
    'uses' => 'productController@getCategory',
    'as' => 'category.single'
    ]);
```

Controller

```
public function getCategory($category) {
    $singleCategory = Category::find($category);
    return view('pages.category', ['category' => $singleCategory]);
}
```

How do I go from here?

Comment: **How do I go from here?** means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Category.php Model add a relation

```
public function products()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

then you can call

```
$singleCategory->products
```

and you'll get you products by category_id

Answer (score 0):

As per the following lines:

```
$singleCategory = Category::find($category);
return view('pages.category', ['category' => $singleCategory]);
```

`category` list is available on `pages.category` page under `$category`. Its a Collection object, you can access its object by using `foreach()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go from here?

I don't know.

But for your problem, if you want to get the products of a Category just do:

```
$singleCategory = Category::find($category);
$products = $singleCategory->products;
```

(I assume you added a `products` method in your `Category` model, if not, read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Then you can display your products by looping on your products:

```
foreach($products as $product) { 
     echo $product->name; 
}
```

Comment: yes i understand but I think something must be wrong with my view or controller
Trying to get property of non-object (View: ....\resources\views\pages\product.blade.php)